# PXE localboot fails (timer doesn't countdown)

Tags: pxe-boot, syslinux

I'm currently using a Centos PXE server and everything in the menus is working great but no matter what setting I try for local boot countdown it doesn't countdown.  It sets there with
"Automatic boot in 20 seconds" and never changes.

I had read that there is a problem with this and newer versions of syslinux but no one really seemed to have a fix?  Has anyone here had this problem and fixed it this way?  Did you just roll back to an earlier version, or is there a newer better fix?

Thanks,

Comment: you should probably add here your pxelinux menu file; "default"